# turn off or stop different devices in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I need to measure different devices power consumption in Linux. So I plan to measure the power consumption difference when the devices are on and off. But I don't know where to start?

Comment: Which version of embedded linux are you using, what devices do you want to turn on / off ?

Comment: Such as backlight, GPU ... as those listed in powertop. My question is not embedded linux specific, however, I think embedded system developer might know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turning off devices might not be feasible only if you're sure about that you're not using that device. There are tools which can help you to find which application is consuming more power (https://01.org/powertop/) but, I'm not sure whether there's any tools for devices. powertop can help you to identify which app is consuming much power and can help you find out what to do. Hope it'll help!

Comment: Then what do you suggest to measure power consumption to do the measurement? This [article](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/embedded-systems/making-smartphones-powersmarter) shows some researcher uses the same approach. What's your argument that it's not feasible. Powertop does estimate power consumption for different devices, though. But I couldn't figure out its mechanism.

Comment: Well, here's some slight misunderstanding, by turning devices off, I thought you meant, you want to unload the device module. Sorry, about the confusion. Now, lets turn our focus into how powertop works, firstly I'm not a geek in this area, I'm sharing AFAIU, every driver export various information through /sys directory including power related info, for ex. cpu power related various info could be found on /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/, it's same for every devices. All you need to do is get the current status of the device and check whether it's good for powersaving or not.

Comment: If not get the difference. You can also measure various info from /proc directory, like no. of interrupt within few sec, also fetch info from process specific directory under /proc/pidno/ , get the schedstat how it was scheduled, is it context switching too much, if yes it's bad. What cpu governor you're using, check for scheduler tuning knobs for powersaving etc. In short, you need to know in advance that what is good for powersaving and what's current system state is. And sum up the difference. Hope this will give you some idea! :)